# how to run background thread after application termination in iphone?

Tags: iphone

is it possible to run a background thread after the application termination specifically, say after the method applicationWillTerminate call from appdelegate?
is it possible to reflect the thread timer value in application preference after application termination?

Answer (score 0):

No. When the process terminates, all threads terminate. However, there is a way to have the process stay in the background. Read up on iOS 4+ multitasking.

Answer (score 0):

More specifically, see the Completing a Finite-Length Task in the Background section of the iOS Application Programming Guide. Wish I could help more, but having issues myself.